# Trouble with Malloc and Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc

I have a function that reads a text file filled with a word on every line. Here is an example of a text file I'm using

```
and
but
five
follows
four
has
is
like
line
lines
littlest
not
once
one
only
other
six
the
three
twice
two
word
words
```

Code:

```
typedef struct node node_t;

struct node {
    char data[MAX_WORD];
    int term;
    node_t *next;
};

node_t *head; 

int
int_struct(int lines){
    FILE *fp;
    char ch;
    int n = 0, i, switch_num=1, test_first=0, test_first_2=0;
    node_t *node, *curr_add; 
    fp = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    node = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    for (i=1; i<=lines; i++){
        switch_num = 1;
        n=0;
        if (test_first != 0){
            if (test_first_2){
                node = (node_t*)malloc(1000000);
            }
            test_first_2=1;
            while ((ch = getc(fp)) != '\n'){
                node -> term = i;
                node -> data[n] = ch;
                n++;
            }
            curr_add -> next = node;
            curr_add = node;
        }
        else{
            test_first = 1;
            head = curr_add = node;
        }
    }
    curr_add -> next = NULL;
    fclose(fp);
    return num;
}
```

What I want to do is to read each word and add it to a linked list.
However I am having trouble with malloc (at the moment I just add in a lot of bytes) and need advice on how to properly use it inside the function I have. I've done a general search and tried my best to try and do what most examples do. But I still can't seem to get my function working. For example, every time I execute the program it will read and add all the words into the linked list. However, the program crashes on the last word, and returns NULL. If anyone is able to point me in the right direction, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Do we need to use our crystal balls to see the definition of `struct node_t`?  Also, why are you allocating 1 million bytes for each node?  You only need `sizeof(struct node_t)`.  Allocating data for the _word_ is another story.  And so refer to my first question.

Comment: You are using global variables in this function which you haven't defined for us.  You need to paste a complete example of your problem.  And a minimal one too: do you have problems with `malloc` even when not reading from a file?

Comment: As for your crash, it's likely that when `getc` returns `EOF`, you continually loop and add bytes to your word (because `EOF != '\n'`), when actually you should exit the loop.  If this is the case, you ought to have found it immediately if you had used a debugger.

Comment: why can't you consider using fgets and make life easier

Comment: Sorry, first post. I just updated with the structure definition. The only reason I dont put the entire program in is because its big and does some other things that are working fine. But if you really need it I can update the post with the whole function. thanks!

Comment: Going back to what you're saying paddy. Do I need to have a realloc every time I add ch into the data array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issues

1. There are *no checks for return values*. Particularly, `fopen` and `malloc`
   may return `NULL`. If they do, you'll catch a segmentation fault error on the
   first attempt to access the returned value.
2. *Overcomplicated logic*. You don't need these `switch_num`, `test_first` and `test_first_2`
   variables (see sample code below).
3. *No need in `getc`* when you're reading a text file line-by-line - use
   `fgets` instead.
4. *Too many memory allocations*. You don't need more than `sizeof(node_t)` + *length of the line* bytes per line.
5. The allocated *memory is not freed*. The dynamic memory should be freed as
   soon as it is not needed.

### Example using linked list

The following reads a text file into a linked list. Memory is allocated for
each list item, and for each line in the file resulting in `n * 2` memory
allocations, where `n` is the number of lines in the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> /* strerror, strdup */
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct _node {
  unsigned line;
  char *data;
  struct _node *next;
} node_t;


static void
destroy_list(node_t *list)
{
  node_t *node;

  for (node = list; node; node = node->next) {
    if (node->data != NULL)
      free(node->data);
    free(node);
  }
}


static node_t *
create_list_item(const char *data, unsigned line)
{
  node_t *node = calloc(1, sizeof(node_t));

  if (node == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "calloc: %s\n", strerror(errno));
  } else {
    node->line = line;
    node->data = strdup(data);
    if (node->data == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "strdup: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      free(node);
      node = NULL;
    }
  }

  return node;
}


/* Returns pointer to new linked list */
static node_t *
read_file(FILE *fp, char *buf, size_t buf_len)
{
  node_t *list = NULL;
  node_t *prev = NULL;
  node_t *node;
  unsigned i;

  for (i = 0; fgets(buf, buf_len, fp); prev = node) {
    if ((node = create_list_item(buf, ++i)) == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "calloc: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      break;
    }

    if (list == NULL)
      list = node;

    if (prev != NULL)
      prev->next = node;
  }

  return list;
}


static void
print_list(const node_t *list)
{
  const node_t *node;

  for (node = list; node; node = node->next)
    printf("%d: %s", node->line, node->data);
}


int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
  const char *filename = "text.txt";
  char buf[1024] = {0};
  FILE *fp = NULL;
  node_t *list = NULL;

  if (NULL == (fp = fopen(filename, "r"))) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to open file %s: %s\n",
        filename, strerror(errno));
    return 1;
  }

  list = read_file(fp, buf, sizeof(buf));
  fclose(fp);

  if (list) {
    print_list(list);
    destroy_list(list);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

### Example using dynamic array

It is inefficient to allocate memory for each line (twice) in the file,
not only because the system calls (`malloc`, `realloc`, etc.) are costly,
but also because the items are placed non-contiguously. Accessing contiguous
region of memory is usually faster.

In the following code, the linked list is replaced with dynamic array. We
initialize memory for 10 lines at once. The size is increased as necessary.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> /* strerror, strdup */
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct _node {
  size_t line;
  char *data;
} node_t;


static void
destroy_array(node_t *array, size_t size)
{
  size_t i;
  node_t *item;

  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    item = &array[i];
    if (item->data)
      free(item->data);
  }
  free(array);
}


static void
print_array(node_t *array, size_t size)
{
  size_t i;
  node_t *item;

  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    item = &array[i];
    if (item->data) {
      printf("%ld: %s", item->line, item->data);
    }
  }
}

static node_t *
read_file(FILE *fp, char *buf, size_t buf_len,
    const size_t array_step, size_t *array_size)
{
  node_t *item;
  node_t *array = calloc(array_step, sizeof(node_t));
  size_t size = 0;
  if (array == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "calloc:%s\n", strerror(errno));
    return array;
  }

  while (fgets(buf, buf_len, fp)) {
    if (size && size % array_step == 0) {
      array = realloc(array, sizeof(node_t) * (array_step + size));
      if (array == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "realloc:%s\n", strerror(errno));
        break;
      }
    }
    item = &array[size++];

    item->line = size;
    item->data = strdup(buf);
    if (item->data == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "strdup: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      break;
    }
  }

  *array_size = size;

  return array;
}

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
  node_t *array;
  const size_t array_step = 10;
  size_t array_size;
  const char *filename = "text.txt";
  char buf[1024] = {0};
  FILE *fp = NULL;

  if (NULL == (fp = fopen(filename, "r"))) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to open file %s: %s\n",
        filename, strerror(errno));
    return 1;
  }

  array = read_file(fp, buf, sizeof(buf), array_step, &array_size);
  fclose(fp);

  if (array) {
    print_array(array, array_size);
    destroy_array(array, array_size);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Note the changes in `node_t` structure.